# How to add a few points to the "current page text area" of tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is my code:

```
\node[anchor=north east] at (current page text area.north east) {Hello};
```

It is positioned right at the top right corner of the page text area. I want to position it a bit lower (by 10pt) and a bit to the left (by 15pt). How do I do this?

Comment: You can do this with the calc library. Put `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` in your preamble and then use `\node[anchor=north east] at ($(current page text area.north east) - (15pt, 10pt)$) {Hello};`.

Comment: @Willoughby works perfectly!

Comment: You don't need any library if use `\path` command (`\node` is an alias for `\path node`):     `\path (current page text area.north east)  ++(-15pt, -10pt) node[anchor=north east]  {Hello};`

Comment: How have you defined the node `current page text area`? I can use the node `current page` but not the node `current page text area`.

Comment: There are also `shift`, `xshift` and `yshift` but I can't find `current page text area` in the TikZ manual.

Comment: @CarLaTeX `shift`, `xshift` and `yshift` commands would not affect to an already defined node (unless you define a `canvas transformation`, that I do not recommend).

Comment: @SergioLlorente The shifting of the coordinates works, see my answer.

Comment: Yes, and it is interesting. So `\tikz{\path (0,0) node (A) {A} [xshift=5cm] node at (A) {Hello};` is not equivalent to `\tikz{\path (0,0) node (A) {A} node at ([xshift=5cm]A) {Hello};}`, which is equivalente to `\tikz{\path (0,0) node (A) {A} [xshift=5cm] node at (0,0) {Hello};}` I didn't know that.

Comment: @SergioLlorente You could ask a question to have an answer by some TikZ expert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the `calc` package from tikz.
Include

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
```

in the preamble of your document, then replace what you have with

```
\node[anchor=north east] at ($(current page text area.north east) - (15pt, 10pt)$) {Hello};
```

The general syntax is

```
\node at ($(node 1) + (x, y)$) {};
```

which will place a node `x` along from `node 1` and `y` up. The default units are centimeters but you can change to points by adding `pt` after the quantity.

See the [tikz manual](https://pgf-tikz.github.io/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) for more details, specifically page 582, the section entitled "Calc Library".

Note you need to load the [`tikzpagenodes` package](https://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzpagenodes/tikzpagenodes.pdf) with `\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}` in your preamble to be able to use the node `current page text area`.

Comment: I can't find `current page text area` in the TikZ manual.

Comment: Your right, neither can I, I just assume the question asker has it as a node somehow since it seems to work for them.

Comment: @CarLaTeX these nodes are defined in package `tikzpagenodes`.

Comment: @Ignasi Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 4):

With `shift`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north east] at ([shift={(-15pt,-10pt)}]current page text area.north east) {Hello};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Or `xshift` and `yshift`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north east] at ([xshift=-15pt,yshift=-10pt]current page text area.north east) {Hello};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks to Ignasi for telling me about `tikzpagenodes`.

Thanks to Sergio Llorente for pointing out the need of `[remember picture,overlay]`.

To show that the shifting works, here I compare the shifted node (filled with red) with the original node (filled with yellow):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north east, fill=yellow] at (current page text area.north east) {Hello};
\node[anchor=north east, fill=red] at ([shift={(-15pt,-10pt)}]current page text area.north east) {Hello};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I think you forgot the options `[overlay, remember picture]` in the tikzpicture enivironement.

Comment: @SergioLlorente You're right, it's always needed with `tikzpagenodes`! Thanks!