# How can I increase the header separation in IEEEtran style?

Tags: spacing, formatting, header-footer, packages, margins

I am trying to add some separation between my header and my text in IEEEtran style document in latex.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal, a4paper, 11pt]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\linespread{1.25}\selectfont


\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{url}       
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% ENCABEZADO DE LAS PÁGINAS TIPO UNICAFAM %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\MYhead}{\smash{\scriptsize
\hfil\parbox[t][\height][t]{\textwidth}{\centering
\begin{picture}(0,0) \put(-30,-27){\includegraphics[width=17mm]{images/00_general/cranfield_university_main_logo.png}} \end{picture} \hspace{6.4cm}
PRÁCTICA DE CIRCUITOS I \hspace{5.15cm} Versión 1.0\\
\hspace{5.2cm} DEPARTAMENTO DE INGENIERÍA DE TELECOMUNICACIONES \hspace{3cm} Periodo 2022-II\\
\underline{\hspace{ \textwidth}}}\hfil\hbox{}}}

\makeatletter
% normal pages
\def\ps@headings{%
\def\@oddhead{\MYhead}%
\def\@evenhead{\MYhead}}%
% title page
\def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{%
\def\@oddhead{\MYhead}%
\def\@evenhead{\MYhead}}%
\makeatother
% make changes take effect
\pagestyle{headings}
% adjust as needed
\addtolength{\footskip}{0\baselineskip}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-10\baselineskip}


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}



% Titulo
\title{\textbf{\huge{This is the title}} \\ 
\vspace{5mm}
\large{Group Design Project} \\
\vspace{5mm}
\large{\textbf{Astronautics and Space Engineering MSc.}} \\
\vspace{3mm}
\normalsize{Academic year: 2022-2023}
}

% author names 
\author{\textbf{\textbf{Yi Qiang Ji Zhang}}\textsuperscript{1} \\ \vspace{3mm}
        \textbf{Supervisors}: Dr. s\textsuperscript{1} \& Dr. s\textsuperscript{1} \\ \vspace{3mm}

        \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{images/00_general/cranfield_university_main_logo.png}
            \hspace{3mm}
            \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{images/00_general/Cranfield_Crest.jpg}
        \end{figure}
        
        \begin{flushleft}
        \small{\textsuperscript{1}\textit{School of Aerospace, Transport and Manufacturing, Cranfield University, United Kingdom}}
        \end{flushleft}


}% <-this % stops a space


\onecolumn
\maketitle
\vspace{-10mm}



\end{document}
```

I tried adding `\vspace{10mm}` and oher approaches but nothing changes it.

I also want the **page numbering** to appear in the right (where there is Version 1.0 written), how can I add that as well to my header?

Comment: If this is for publication, don't mess with the page format.  I would be very surprised if company or university logos were allowed at all, much less in the heaser.

Comment: If it is for a university submission, usually they provide Latex templates for this kind of thing. I would try to find them first! If they exist, you will save yourself a lot of time.

Comment: @JohnKormylo This is for university, it's a personal template I am crafting for my assignments.

Comment: @Jes I am doing this for an assignment myself and there is no restriction. My uni provides some templates but I want to add something :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility to generate the header is to use `tikz` with the options of `remember picture, overlay,transform shape`, which basically overlaps a tikz-generated header on top of the page. At the end of this message, I put the code to do that. What I am doing:

1. I changed the top margin to 2.5 cm via the `geometry` package to leave space for the header.
2. I generated the header using `tikz` and multiline nodes, since it allows for centering of the text without having to guess its position via `hspace`.
3. I place the different nodes approximately 1cm above the text body and the line between them via the `calc` library.

Do note that all of this positioning is manual. If you change the value for the top margin in the declaration of the `geometry` package, you will need to adjust the different sizes manually.

The text does not overlap the header because the header has been placed *above* the text body (!) which removes the problem that you had before. Other possibility to achieve a similar effect without having to change how to generate the header can be enveloping your header in a `minipage` environment with a set height, but I am not sure if this will work.

I hope it helps you!

The result is the following:
[image]

And the code to achieve this:

```
\documentclass[journal, a4paper, 11pt]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\linespread{1.25}\selectfont


\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{url}       
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry} %<- Here I changed the top value to make space for the header!
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}          % Extra!
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes} % To employ the command "current page text area" for positioning of tikz nodes
\usetikzlibrary{calc}      % To help with positioning
\usepackage{lipsum}        % To generate fake text

%\usepackage{showframe}     % To show page geometry
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% ENCABEZADO DE LAS PÁGINAS TIPO UNICAFAM %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\MYhead}{%
    \scriptsize
    \hfil\parbox[t][\height][t]{\textwidth}{%
    \centering
    \begin{picture}(0,0) \put(-30,-27){%
    \includegraphics[width=17mm]{example-image-a}}%
    \end{picture}% 
    \hfill PRÁCTICA DE CIRCUITOS I \hfill Versión 1.0 - Page \thepage\\
\hfill DEPARTAMENTO DE INGENIERÍA DE TELECOMUNICACIONES \hfill Periodo 2022-II\\
\underline{\hspace{\textwidth}}}\hfil\hbox{}}

\newcommand{\tikZHeader}{%
% Useful links: 
% For relative positioning: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89588/positioning-relative-to-page-in-tikz
% Ikz and overlay: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121393/tikz-header-and-footer-across-top-and-bottom-of-bulletin-newsletter-page
% Calc library: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/617027/how-to-add-a-few-points-to-the-current-page-text-area-of-tikz
% Maybe the header is better with the fancyheader package? : https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Headers_and_footers
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,transform shape]
%- Node with university logo (left side) -%
\node (leftText) [anchor = south west, inner sep=0pt] % Anchors are tricky! 
    at ($(current page text area.north west) - (0cm,-1cm)$) % Put the node at the upper left (north west) side of the body of text. Then add 1 cm towards the top of the page, so it is separated from the text.
    {%
     \includegraphics[width=17mm]{example-image-a}%
     };
%- Node with text on center of page -%
\node (centerText) [anchor = south, inner sep=0pt, style={align=center, font = \scriptsize}]
    at ($(current page text area.north) - (0cm,-1cm)$) % Put the node at the upper center (north) side of the body of text. Then add 1 cm towards the top of the page, so it is separated from the text.
    {%
        PRÁCTICA DE CIRCUITOS I \\ DEPARTAMENTO DE INGENIERÍA DE TELECOMUNICACIONES \\ Periodo 2022-II
    }; 
%- Node with text on right side -%
\node (rightText) [anchor = south east, inner sep=0pt, style={align=right, font = \scriptsize}] 
    at ($(current page text area.north east) - (0cm,-1cm)$) % Put the node at the upper right (north east) side of the body of text. Then add 1 cm towards the top of the page, so it is separated from the text.
    {%
    Versión 1.0 - Page \thepage
    }; 
%- Line below header -%
\draw ($(current page text area.north west) - (0cm,-0.5cm)$) -- ($(current page text area.north east) - (0cm,-0.5cm)$) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\makeatletter
% normal pages
\def\ps@headings{%
\def\@oddhead{\tikZHeader}%
\def\@evenhead{\tikZHeader}}%
% title page
\def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{%
\def\@oddhead{\tikZHeader}%
\def\@evenhead{\tikZHeader}}%
\makeatother
% make changes take effect
\pagestyle{headings}
% adjust as needed
\addtolength{\footskip}{0\baselineskip}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-10\baselineskip}

\pagenumbering{Roman}

\begin{document}

% Titulo
\title{ \vspace*{15mm} \textbf{\huge{This is the title}} \\ 
\vspace{5mm}
\large{Group Design Project} \\
\vspace{5mm}
\large{\textbf{Astronautics and Space Engineering MSc.}} \\
\vspace{3mm}
\normalsize{Academic year: 2022-2023}
}

% author names 
\author{\textbf{\textbf{Yi Qiang Ji Zhang}}\textsuperscript{1} \\ \vspace{3mm}
        \textbf{Supervisors}: Dr. s\textsuperscript{1} \& Dr. s\textsuperscript{1} \\ \vspace{3mm}

        \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-b}
            \hspace{3mm}
            \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-c}
        \end{figure}
        
        \begin{flushleft}
        \small{\textsuperscript{1}\textit{School of Aerospace, Transport and Manufacturing, Cranfield University, United Kingdom}}
        \end{flushleft}


}% <-this % stops a space


\onecolumn
\maketitle

\newpage

\lipsum[10-25] % fake text


\end{document}
```

Comment: That is a really clever way to do it! Thanks a lot Jes! I did not thought of that and it just works ahahah! Maybe there is other more "elegant" ways to solve it but for now I think it's really good approach! Thanks a lot for your time and help!

Comment: Glad to help! Sometimes I like to play around with tikz, so I saw the chance and took it :)

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to include the `vspace*` command directly within the title one:

```
\title{ \vspace*{5mm} \textbf{\huge{This is the title}} \\
```

That worked for me to shift everything down.

Regarding changing the page numbering to the top right, you can modify the `\MYhead` command to achieve so via the `\thepage` command. Do note that, in order for the first page to be also in roman, you need to write the `\pagenumbering{Roman}` before the `\begin{document}`. The modification is as such:

```
\newcommand{\MYhead}{\smash{\scriptsize
\hfil\parbox[t][\height][t]{\textwidth}{\centering
\begin{picture}(0,0) \put(-30,-27){\includegraphics[width=17mm]{images/00_general/cranfield_university_main_logo.png}} \end{picture} \hspace{6.4cm}
PRÁCTICA DE CIRCUITOS I \hspace{5.15cm} Versión 1.0 - Page \thepage\\ % <-- HERE!
\hspace{5.2cm} DEPARTAMENTO DE INGENIERÍA DE TELECOMUNICACIONES \hspace{3cm} Periodo 2022-II\\
\underline{\hspace{ \textwidth}}}\hfil\hbox{}}}
```

And finally, the resulting code with the modifications:

```
\documentclass[journal, a4paper, 11pt]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\linespread{1.25}\selectfont


\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{url}       
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% ENCABEZADO DE LAS PÁGINAS TIPO UNICAFAM %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\MYhead}{\smash{\scriptsize
\hfil\parbox[t][\height][t]{\textwidth}{\centering
\begin{picture}(0,0) \put(-30,-27){\includegraphics[width=17mm]{images/00_general/cranfield_university_main_logo.png}} \end{picture} \hspace{6.4cm}
PRÁCTICA DE CIRCUITOS I \hspace{5.15cm} Versión 1.0 - Page \thepage\\
\hspace{5.2cm} DEPARTAMENTO DE INGENIERÍA DE TELECOMUNICACIONES \hspace{3cm} Periodo 2022-II\\
\underline{\hspace{ \textwidth}}}\hfil\hbox{}}}

\makeatletter
% normal pages
\def\ps@headings{%
\def\@oddhead{\MYhead}%
\def\@evenhead{\MYhead}}%
% title page
\def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{%
\def\@oddhead{\MYhead}%
\def\@evenhead{\MYhead}}%
\makeatother
% make changes take effect
\pagestyle{headings}
% adjust as needed
\addtolength{\footskip}{0\baselineskip}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-10\baselineskip}

\pagenumbering{Roman}

\begin{document}

% Titulo
\title{ \vspace*{5mm} \textbf{\huge{This is the title}} \\ 
\vspace{5mm}
\large{Group Design Project} \\
\vspace{5mm}
\large{\textbf{Astronautics and Space Engineering MSc.}} \\
\vspace{3mm}
\normalsize{Academic year: 2022-2023}
}

% author names 
\author{\textbf{\textbf{Yi Qiang Ji Zhang}}\textsuperscript{1} \\ \vspace{3mm}
        \textbf{Supervisors}: Dr. s\textsuperscript{1} \& Dr. s\textsuperscript{1} \\ \vspace{3mm}

        \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{images/00_general/cranfield_university_main_logo.png}
            \hspace{3mm}
            \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{images/00_general/Cranfield_Crest.jpg}
        \end{figure}
        
        \begin{flushleft}
        \small{\textsuperscript{1}\textit{School of Aerospace, Transport and Manufacturing, Cranfield University, United Kingdom}}
        \end{flushleft}


}% <-this % stops a space


\onecolumn
\maketitle

asdsda

\newpage

asdasd

\newpage

asdasd


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks!! That fixes the title page!!! But the other subsequent pages still have the same problem... is there a global command that can be applied to all pages?

Comment: I am uncertain if something like that exists. What about changing the approach to generating the header? I will post a new answer using 'tikz', which is a powerful tool for things like this!